# Goutte crawler get style

Tags: php, web-scraping, goutte, domcrawler

I am using Goutte crawler.
So, for the few hours, I was trying to get a style attribute of a div in a search page with specific query, and this style have a Background-img.
So first I made a GET request to the url by

```
   $crawler = $client->request('GET',"https://www.esheeq.net/search/مسلسل+علي+رضا");
```

and then crawled it by

```
$crawler->filter(".imgBg")->attr("style")
```

and printed it, and it worked, but the problem is when I change the search query such as ([https://www.esheeq.net/search/مسلسل+الغرفة+الحمراء](https://www.esheeq.net/search/%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%84+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%BA%D8%B1%D9%81%D8%A9+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A1)), it throw an error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty. in C:\xampp\htdocs\esheeqAPI\vendor\symfony\dom-crawler\Crawler.php:550 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\esheeqAPI\api\functions.php(8): Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler->attr('style') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\esheeqAPI\api\tests.php(4): InsertMultipleSeries() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\esheeqAPI\vendor\symfony\dom-crawler\Crawler.php on line 550
```

but when I open the url I requested it show me a div of class imgBg that have a style attribute. Then why I am getting error, and how can I solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe try doing this instead:

```
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

// you need to urlencode arabic characters, because php doesn't do that automatically

$url = "https://www.esheeq.net/search/" . urlencode( "مسلسل+الغرفة+الحمراء" );

$html_content = file_get_contents($url);

// and then;
$crawler = new Crawler( $html_content );

$crawler->filter(".imgBg")->attr("style");
```

let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: no, i am getting an errror : Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.esheeq.net/search/مسلسل+الغرفة+الحمراء): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in...